# Query not giving correct results (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, temp-tables

I'm getting a weird result from a quite long query, which I will simplify here:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table1 AS
(SELECT 
parent.id as parent_id,
times.a_time,
times.sequence,
FROM times
LEFT JOIN parent ON times.parent_id=parent.id
WHERE times.stop_id=10);

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS table2;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table2 AS
(SELECT 
parent.id as parent_id,
times.b_time,
times.sequence,
FROM times
LEFT JOIN parent ON times.parent_id=parent.id
WHERE times.stop_id=15 );

--here comes PDO->exec();

SELECT table1.*, table2.b_time
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.parent_id=table2.parent_id
WHERE table2.parent_id IS NOT NULL AND table1.sequence<table2.sequence
ORDER BY table1.a_time
```

I'm testing the query using EMS MySQL Manager 2007, and in PHP I'm using PDO query.

In order to get the final result, (I know that PDO doesn't support running this full query at once and giving back the result set), I run `PDO->exec()` after temporary tables creation (see comment in the query), and then I run `PDO->query()` on the last `SELECT`:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$tempTablesSQL='DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS...'; //create temporary tables
$db->exec($tempTablesSQL);

$sql='SELECT table1.*, table2.b_time ...'; //JOIN and SELECT the results
$results=array();
foreach($db->query($sql) as $row){
  $results[]=$row;
}

print_r($results);
```

In MySQL Manager I run the whole query at once, and for those specific IDs I'm getting 29 rows as result (which is correct, because the records are inserted from a previously parsed file, and by comparing the results to the file I know they are good).

But in PHP, I'm getting only 25 results, and totally wrong values for `b_time`.

So, my questions are:

- **why do I get wrong results?**
- **is my approach of calling this query wrong (in PHP)?**

Any help is appreciated.

--**EDIT**--

It's not just PDO, I tried with mysqli_multi_query, I'm getting the same wrong results.

One important thing I noticed is: if I use regular tables instead of the temporary, the results are fine.

Comment: We can not see your 1) `I run the whole query at once` 2) inserted from a previously parsed **file** 3) your PHP PDO INSERT Sql. You should give us a example we can follow. real code , real query . I'm shure you can give us a short test code.

Comment: @moskito-x Well, this is the query I'm running, I just removed a few joins that are not important for the results (I tested it both with the full query and the simplified one). It's a simple join of two temp tables. There are no issues with the inserts and the parsed file, the data in the database is fine, only this query misbehaves.

Comment: this is useless `$sql='...'; //final SELECT`

Comment: @moskito-x That is `$sql='SELECT table1.*, table2.b_time
FROM table1' LEFT JOIN table2 ...` (second part of the query, it's stated in my question)

Comment: Can you provide a sqlfiddle with data for both tables?

Comment: and now show us : the **query** from `I run the whole query at once` .

Comment: @moskito-x `I run the whole query at once` regards the execution in EMS MySQL Manager, or phpMyAdmin, or mysql console. To my knowledge, the full query can't be run with PDO->query (because it contains multiple statements), that's why I run it in two steps: exec() and query().

Comment: I Know, but we can't see your `whole query`

Comment: @moskito-x This is the whole query, it's written on top of the question. `Whole query = drop and create temp table1 + drop and create temp table2 + join and select`, just runned at once in mysql console, instead of calling `exec()` and `query()` in PHP

Comment: You asked us for help . We should compare different results. One comes from PHP PDO and the other is produced with `MySQL Manager` . We can only see the PHP part. How can we be sure that both commands are absolutely the same?

Comment: @moskito-x I'm just doing copy/paste from editor to editor, they are  absolutely the same.

Comment: @ekstrakt Did you find answers any helpful?

Comment: @peterm I created the procedure, but I'm still getting differences between results executed in PHP/PDO and mysql ... So now I'm trying to pull out some sample data and to create sqlfiddle

Comment: @peterm there is too much data to create sqlfiddle (it only allows 8000 characters for DDL and DLM). But one thing I noticed in between tests, is that if I use regular tables instead of temporary, I'm getting good results. (but I can't use regular tables for this task, the results are the output for a search function a user performs)

Comment: @ekstrakt There's no need to pull all data in. Just relevant amount to reproduce the problem. Now I'd recommend to reconsider using subqueries instead of temp tables. That we can probably help you with (the query) when you put together appropriate sqlfiddle.

Comment: @peterm I can't pull just a small amount of data to intersect the tables, I have to search for it manually. But it's 5am here, so I hope I'll find an answer tomorrow ... thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Let my try to put a couple of suggestions on the second part of your question which is ***is my approach of calling this query wrong?***

First of all it looks like you don't need to create any temp tables. Based on what you showed the whole thing can be a single query like

```sql
SELECT q1.parent_id, q1.a_time, q1.sequence, q2.b_time
  FROM
(
    SELECT p.id parent_id, t.a_time, t.sequence
      FROM times t LEFT JOIN parent p
        ON t.parent_id=p.id
     WHERE t.stop_id = ?
 ) q1 LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT p.id as parent_id, t.b_time, t.sequence
      FROM times t LEFT JOIN parent p
        ON t.parent_id=parent.id
     WHERE t.stop_id = ?
) q2 ON q2.parent_id IS NOT NULL 
    AND q1.sequence < q2.sequence
 ORDER BY q1.a_time
```

And execute it as a prepared statement

```php
...
$sql = 'SELECT ...'; // the whole thing from above
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array($stop_id1, $stop_id2));
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($result);
```

Now even if for some reason you have to use temp tables and perform some manipulations along the way before returning the result set then I'd suggest to wrap it up a stored procedure

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_myproc (IN stop_id1 INT, IN stop_id2 INT, ...)
BEGIN
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table1 AS
    ...
    WHERE times.stop_id = stop_id1;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table1 AS
    ...
    WHERE times.stop_id = stop_id2

    -- return the resultset
    SELECT table1.*, table2.b_time
    FROM table1
    ...
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And call your procedure once from php

```php
...
$sql = 'CALL sp_myproc(?, ?)';
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array($stop_id1, $stop_id2));
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($result);
```

Now regarding the first part of your question ***why do I get wrong results?*** `OUTER` joins can be tricky and especially when you chain them. You can easily filter some rows out or produce additional rows (which happens most often).

Those few joins that you removed may be the cause.

Anyway provided information is not enough for conclusive answer.

But I would suggest instead of returning columns as `table1.*` specify all columns explicitly and give explicit aliases for columns that have the same names in different tables that are part of a join.

Comment: Your single query gives me 33000 results (parent has 1900 rows, times has 15000 rows), and the correct number of results should be 53. The reason for temp tables is query execution time (100ms combined vs 600ms, on my computer). I guess I'll go with a procedure.

Comment: @ekstrakt It's impossible to recreate your query correctly and intelligently based on your input and not seeing the real data and desired output. I just put together blindly what you showed us as an example. You can go from there or you can put together a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with test data and then we can help to sort it out.

Comment: @ekstrakt : That's what I want to tell OP the whole time.